# Animating a ui-router state change: div reappears briefly when animation ends

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, css-animations, ng-animate, animate.css

Here's a plunker of the phenomenon: http://plnkr.co/edit/xLfXyDcwKtHPM7Sdhygf?p=preview

Ignore the hideous layout; the problem is evident when you click "log in" - the FadeOutDown animation fires, the div dutifully proceeds towards the bottom of the page, but just as the animation ends it reappears briefly in its original position.

I'm very new to the whole webdev game, so I'm unsure if this problem is to do with ngAnimate, ui-router, or the way I'm using ng-enter/ng-leave in the CSS. I'd obviously like for the div to remain gone once it's faded out of view.

My approach is to trigger a transition via an ui-sref, then animate the transition with this kind of CSS

```
[ui-view].ng-leave #first-div {
    animation: fadeOutDown 1s;
}
```

And so forth for the other divs. It technically works but has this weird artifact at the end of the animation period.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use that:

```
[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  /*padding-left: 0px;*/  
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  /*padding-left: 100px;*/
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/i9wHL9dNbV55EKZr06dn?p=preview

---

You can just add.

Documentation:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#css-based-animations

```
[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added the ng-leave-active changes to my own animation and it seems to work, so I'll accept this as an answer. At some point I will learn why these things are the way they are. (I will upvote you when I have enough rep).